# How to compute integrals using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

> Compute the integral using Riemann sums $$\int_0^s x^2 \,dx$$
> Find the sum $ U_n $ of all rectangles below the function $y = x^3$ 
> Find the sum $O_n$ of all rectangles above the function $y = x^3$ 
> Take the limits to show that
> $$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞}U_n = \lim \limits_{x \to ∞}O_n = \frac{s^3}3$$

I am vaguely familiar with Riemann sums, however, given this problem I really am not sure how to approach it.
I know that $\Delta$*x* = $\frac{s}n$ and I know that $x_i$ = $\frac{si}n$.
The next thing I believe I am supposed to do is compute $f(x_i) = (\frac{si}n)^2$ and then use that to compute $$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞} \sum_{i=0}^n [\frac{s^2i^2}{n^2}]·\frac{s}n $$
At this point it feels like things start getting convoluted and I am not sure how I would use this to find the sum of the rectangles above and below the function $y=x^3$.

Guidance to solving this question would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's the limit a *n* tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out what can be factored:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s^2i^2}{n^2}·\frac{s}n=\frac{s^3}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{s^3}{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
for the upper Riemann sum, and almost the same for the lower one ($i=0$ to $n-1$).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I just wanted to clarify for the lower Riemann sum would the equation be (n(n-1)(2n-1))/6?  Also, is the second ∑ supposed to be ∑i^2 instead of n^2?

Comment: Yes, it's correct for the lower sum. Thanks for pointing the typo, I'll fix it instantly!

Comment: Once again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2}{n^3} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3} = \frac{1}{3}  $$

Answer (score 1):

If we have function where $f'>0$ in the domain such as this, if we take the area of the rectangle in a given area $x\in[a,b]$ then it is clear that $(b-a)f(b)>A$ and $(b-a)f(a)<A$ so we end up with a limit we can squeeze:
$$(b-a)f(a)<A<(b-a)f(b)$$
now to cover the whole domain we are interested in just take the sum